# Sketch the graph of g. How do I go about doing this? What are the techniques?

Tags: calculus

What technique should I utilize to sketch this graph?

I am specifically asking:

What should I be looking for to give me an idea what the questions is asking for? Given that I have solved the limit what else should this polynomial be communicating to me so that I can sketch it?

I am looking for math jargon free explanations. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your function $g(x)$ is

$$g(x)=\frac{x^2+x-2}{|x-1|}=\frac{(x-1)(x+2)}{|x-1|}=\frac{x-1}{|x-1|}(x+2)$$

That fraction $\frac{x-1}{|x-1|}$ is a variation of the *sign* function of $x-1$: it equals $-1$ when $x<1$, $1$ when $x>1$, and is undefined when $x=1$. You should get to know this "sign" function since it often comes up in problems like these. For example, this "sign" function is the derivative of the absolute value function. Again, note this is *not* the standard sign function, which is zero at $x=0$.

So we write

$$g(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x-1)(x+2)$$

So your graph acts like $-(x+2)$ for $x<1$, like $x+2$ for $x>1$, and is undefined at $x=1$. Those two cases are simple straight lines and the limits of each are obvious. We see the left-hand limit as $x$ approaches $1$ is $-(1+2)=-3$, and the right-hand limit is $1+2=3$. Those limits differ, so the double-sided limit does not exist.

Is that clear? Here is a computer graph, showing the two lines:

[image]